# IIS Virtual Directory access restricted to only one user

Tags: iis, basic-authentication, virtual-directory

Is it possible to restrict access to the content (pdf's) of a virtual directory of the default website in IIS7?

- I needed the virtual directory to authenticate as a domain user, since the source path is an unc path on the network.
- I tried disabling anonymous authentication and enabling basic
  authentication, but using this approach   Every user in the domain
  has access to the pdfs.
- I tried several configurations (allow rules, impersonation, ...) but noting seams to work.

Is this possible simply by configuration in IIS console, or by modifying the web.config?

Answer (score 3):

After all, it was not that hard to achieve.

I needed to add "URL authorization" service to the Web Server Role, after that the "Authorization Rules" appeared in IIS and I could grant access explicitly to a certain user and remove the Allow all user rule.